# Find all pairs of primes $(p, q)$ such that $p^2 + 6pq + q$ is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

Find all pairs of primes $(p, q)$ such that $p^2 + 6pq + q$ is a perfect square.

This is a problem I encountered a month ago. I remember having had multiple attempts, but they didn't seem to lead anywhere useful; I can't remember what they were now.

If my memory serves me right, a few of my attempts involved quadratic residues (quadratic reciprocity-ish), and desperately trying to work on cases.

How can one approach this problem?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuU8c.jpg): A picture of the test paper the problem is from. The language is Vietnamese.

Comment: Should the last term be $q^2$?  Just guessing, but the other terms are all quadratic in $p,q$.  More to the point:  what have you tried?  Have you found some examples?

Comment: The last term is q. 

I don't remember all my attempts back then, since it has been roughly a month. The only things I remember is that I tried using quadratic residues:
p^2 + 6pq + q = a^2
By taking mod p and q, I deduce that (p^2/q) = 1 (this is a matter of fact) and (q/p) = 1 
 ( which means q^{(p - 1)/2} = 1 modulo p ). I struggle to get anything useful after (assuming p, q are odds). 

Case-bashing didn't work well; actually I think I made some mistakes. So I'd rather not mentioning it here.

If by examples you mean, if I've tried searching the question elsewhere, I did.

Comment: By examples, I meant examples.  Pairs $(p,q)$ that work.  There seem to be loads of them.  $(5,41)$ for instance.  Any reason to imagine that the full list is interesting?

Comment: It might be possible that the solutions are of a generalized form, but I think I've got no idea right now.

Comment: But what makes this interesting?   The quadratic one has a simple solution (I think).  This one seems entirely random.  $(37,149)$ works, for instance.   I mean, maybe it can be changed into Pell form or something like that, but if it is just a random expression...

Comment: I believe it's not a random expression as a result of thousands of guesses. Since it's of competition math, it should be solvable without the use of calculators or computers. It might be a not-good-looking expression, but there will probably be a way to manually derive it.

Comment: $(97,389)$ works.  Please provide a link to this competition.

Comment: There isn't a link, but I do have a picture of the printed contest paper. How do I send images?
Edit: I have added it in my post

Comment: Ah, well...I have no guess.  The list of examples looks entirely random and it seems to be easy to find solutions.  My only thought is that they meant to put $q^2$ instead of $q$.  In that case, working $\pmod 3$ we get $p^2+q^2\equiv 0 \pmod 3$ which forces one of the primes to be $3$.

Comment: That's possible and would be really disappointing if it was merely a typo. I think I'll continue pretending it's not a typo; until I've failed sufficient times to be convinced so.

Comment: The existence of fairly large examples, like $(71,569)$ tends to rule out simple congruence methods, or simple lists for that matter.

Comment: Friends of mine noticed that q= 4p + 1 and q = 8p + 1 are always the solutions, and this is provable. But the rest are not yet known. The solutions you provided are also ones of these cases.

Comment: @lulu It is a typo. The nice thing about $p^2 + 6 pq + q^2 = r^2$  can have only a few prime solutions, as all  are $p = u^2 - uv = u(u-v) \; , \; \; $  $q = uv + v^2 = v(u+v) \; , \; \; $ and $r = u^2 + 2uv - v^2. $   This is similar to Pythagorean triples.   Then in order to have both $p,q$  prime, the integers $u,v$  are quite restricted.

Comment: Thanks for adding the image. Not that I could read the text, but we can ascertain that the contest has been held. Not that I could read a due date in there either, but because the text is there, this works :-)

Comment: In the few solutions that I found it seems to always be that $a$ is one of $p\pm q$. Is this always the case?

Comment: $a=p\pm q$ correspond exactly to the solutions $p=4q+1$ and $p=8q+1$.

Comment: Answering the above. Nope. There are solutions like $p=139$, $q=89$ with $a=5q-p$. Obviously we always have $a\equiv\pm p\pmod q$, and I entertained some hopes that this would take us forward.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen what is "answering the above"?

Comment: @cineel The "conjecture" I made two comments earlier. That we always have $a=p\pm q$. Easily refuted.

Comment: why was this question closed? is it too hard?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is difficult (barring some typo). I cannot solve it, but I share my thoughts and very modest findings. Nothing much here, I'm afraid.

The equation
$$
a^2=p^2+6pq+q
$$
implies that $a^2\equiv p^2\pmod q$. Taking into account that $q$ is a prime, this implies that $a\equiv\pm p\pmod q$. Because we can replace $a$ with $-a$ without affecting anything, we can assume that we have the plus sign, and hence $a=p+kq$ for some integer $k$. Plugging that into the original equation leads to the equation
$$k^2q-1=(6-2k)p.\qquad(*)$$
Here the left hand side is always positive, so $k<3$. The right hand side is always even, implying that $k$ is odd (and $q>2$). Also $k$ cannot be a multiple of $3$ because then so is the r.h.s. but the l.h.s. is not. But, there seem to be solutions for many values of $k$ (if not all $k$ subject to the above constraints):

- If $k=1$ then $(*)$ implies $q=4p+1$. Many primes work here (see the comments).
- If $k=-1$ then similarly $(*)$ implies $q=8p+1$. The same applies.
- If $k=-5$ we get the equation $25q-1=16p$. Modulo $16$ we get $q\equiv 9$, so $q=16r+9$ and $p=25r+14$ for some integer $r$. Here $r=5$ and $r=17$ lead to solutions (the only ones with $r<40$).
- If $k=-7$ we similarly arrive first at $49q-1=20p$ and then $q=20r+9$, $p=49r+22$ for some integer $r$. Here $r=1,3,19$ work (the only solutions with $r<60$).

I don't see any chance of classifying the solutions this way. I'm not a number theorist but IIRC even the simplest similar question:  Are there infinitely many integers $r$ such that $r$ and $2r+1$ are both primes (i.e. infinitude of Sophie Germain primes) is open? I have the impression that many people think there are infinitely many Sophie Germain prime pairs. If only because there is even a conjecture that there are arbitrarily long chains of Sophie Germain pairs: $(r,2r+1)$, $(2r+1,4r+3)$, $\ldots$. Look up Cunningham chains for more information.

Of course, it is natural to think that the lists of prime pairs relevant to this problem: $(4r+1,r)$, $(8r+1,r)$, $(16r+9,25r+14)$, $(20r+9,49r+22)$, $\ldots$, are all sparser than the lists of Sophie Germain pairs. If only because the numbers grow a bit faster here. Anyway, these observations suggest to me that it is extremely difficult to decide whether there are infinitely many prime pair solutions $(p,q)$.

:-(

Comment: An addendum to this (great) answer: If $m=-k$ is relatively prime to $6$ and positive, then we seek prime pairs $(p,q)$ for which $m^2q-1=(2m+6)p$. Letting $0\leq r<2m+6$ satisfy
$$r\equiv 1/m^2\pmod{2m+6},$$
we seek integer $n$ for which both
$$p=m^2n+\frac{m^2r-1}{2m+6}\text{ and }q=(2m+6)n+r$$
are prime. One can check that there are no congruence conditions prohibiting this (i.e. no prime $\ell$ that must divide one of these expressions for any $n$), and so [Dickson's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson%27s_conjecture) predicts infinitely many prime pair for each such $m$.

Comment: Thanks @CarlSchildkraut! I was contemplating about asking a general question along those lines. Like, what is known about the frequency of two arithmetic sequences both having primes at the same position.

Comment: I'd expect "standard conjectures" to say that $an+b$ and $cn+d$ should be both prime for $\Theta(N/\log^2(N))$ values of $1\leq n\leq N$, given the rough heuristic that the primality of these terms should be independent up to divisibility by a few specific primes. There's probably a way to find all of these annoying primes and guess the right constant, too.

Answer (score 1):

$p^2+6pq+q=a^2$  -----(1)

Eqn. (1) has parametric solution:

$p=w$

$q=4w+1$

$a=5w+1$

We take $(4w+1)$ a prime for prime 'w'. And we get:

$(p,q,a)=(1,5,6)=(3,13,16)=(13,53,66)=(37,149,186)$

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is all of them.

We want triples $p$, $q$, and $m$ so that
$p^2+6pq+q=m^2$ where p and q are prime and m is some integer.

Alternatively, $(p+3q)^2+q=m^2+9q^2$ by completing the square.

First consider whether p or q is an even prime, i.e. 2. We clearly have no $m$ if $p$ and $q$ are both 2. If $q$ is 2 and $p$ is an odd prime, the left side of the equation is congruent to 3 modulo 4, and the right is a perfect square, an impossibility.

Now suppose $p$=2 and $q$ is an odd prime. Then the equation becomes $4+13q=m^2$. Or, $13q=(m-2)(m+2)$. $13q$ can only be expressed as a product two ways, $13q=1\cdot 13q$ or $13q=13\cdot q $. The first factorization implies $m=3$ and $13q=5$, not possible. We don't know which is the greater of $13$ and $q$ so try two cases. If $m-2=13$ then $m+2=17=q$. So we have our first $(p,q,m)$ triplet, (2,17,15). Assuming $m+2=13$ implies $q=9$, not prime so it is not a solution.

This process can be iterated for the next several primes 3,5,7,11...

1. Pick a prime $p$
2. $(6p+1)q=(m-p)(m+p)$.
3. Each permitted factorization implies a value for m which in turn implies a value for q, i.e. If $(m-p)=(6p+1)$ then $m=7p+1$ and $q=8p+1$. Discard if q is composite.
4. Step 3 effectively yields the triple $(p,8p+1,7p+1)$ or $(p,4p+1,5p+1)$ depending on if the implied $q$ is prime. So we have (3,13,16), (5,41,36), (7,29,36), (11,89,78), (13,53,66).

Regardless if that is all of them, some properties hold in general. For odd $p$ and $q$, the equation implies $m$ is even. The alternative form implies $q$ must be congruent to 1 modulo 4, consistent with solutions above. Any prime other than 3 is congruent to 1 or -1 modulo 3, so its square is 1. Applying this to the alternative form of the equation tells us that $q$ is congruent to 2 modulo 3, otherwise $m^2$ would be congruent to 2 modulo 3, not possible. It follows that $m$ is divisible by 3. It's already been established at $m$ is even, so the preceding implies $m$ is divisible by 6 if p is not 3.

If we have $q=2 (mod \ 3)$ and $q=1 (mod \ 4)$, the Chinese remainder theorem tells us $q=5 (mod \ 12)$, further narrowing the possibilities.